# c++ : Is there a faster way to get the intersection of map/unordered_map?

Tags: python, c++, dictionary, set, intersection

Is there a faster way to the following in c++, so that i can outperform the python's implementation?

- Get intersection of two map/unordered_map keys
- For these intersected keys, compute the pairwise difference between elements of their respective set/unordered_set
  Some info that might be useful:
- hash_DICT1 has about O(10000)keys, and about O(10) elements in the each set.
- hash_DICT2 has about O(1000)keys, and about O(1)  elements in the each set.

For example:

```cpp
    map <int,set<int>> hash_DICT1;
        hash_DICT1[1] = {1,2,3};
        hash_DICT1[2] = {4,5,6};
    map <int,set<int>> hash_DICT2;
        hash_DICT2[1] = {11,12,13};
        hash_DICT2[3] = {4,5,6};

    vector<int> output_vector
        = GetPairDiff(hash_DICT1, hash_DICT2)
        = [11-1,12-1,13-1, 
           11-2,12-2,13-2, 
           11-3,12-3,13-3] // only hashkey=1 is intersect, so only compute pairwise difference of the respective set elements.
        = [10, 11, 12, 
            9, 10, 11, 
            8,  9, 10] // Note that i do want to keep duplicates, if any. Order does not matter.
```

`GetPairDiff` function.

```cpp
    vector<int> GetPairDiff(
    unordered_map <int, set<int>> &hash_DICT1,
    unordered_map <int, set<int>> &hash_DICT2) {
      // Init
        vector<int> output_vector;
        int curr_key;
        set<int> curr_set1, curr_set2;

      // Get intersection
        for (const auto &KEY_SET:hash_DICT2) {
          curr_key = KEY_SET.first;
          // Find pairwise difference
          if (hash_DICT1.count(curr_key) > 0){
            curr_set1 = hash_DICT1[curr_key];
            curr_set2 = hash_DICT2[curr_key];
            for (auto it1=curr_set1.begin(); it1 != curr_set1.end(); ++it1) {
              for (auto it2=curr_set2.begin(); it2 != curr_set2.end(); ++it2) {
                output_vector.push_back(*it2 - *it1);
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

main run

```cpp
    int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
        // Using unordered_map
        unordered_map <int,set<int>> hash_DICT_1;
            hash_DICT_1[1] = {1,2,3};
            hash_DICT_1[2] = {4,5,6};
        unordered <int,set<int>> hash_DICT_2;
            hash_DICT_2[1] = {11,12,13};
            hash_DICT_2[3] = {4,5,6};
        GetPairDiff(hash_DICT_1, hash_DICT_1);
    }
```

Compiled like this

```sh
g++ -o ./CompareRunTime.out -Ofast -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11
```

Other data structures are welcomed, such as `map` or `unordered_set`.
However i did try all 4 permutations, and found the one given by `GetPairDiff` runs the fastest, but nowhere near as fast as the python's implementation:

```py
hash_DICT1 = { 1 : {1,2,3},      2 : {4,5,6} }
hash_DICT2 = { 1 : {11,12,13},   3 : {4,5,6} }

def GetPairDiff(hash_DICT1, hash_DICT2):
    vector = []
    for element in hash_DICT1.keys() & hash_DICT2.keys():
        vector.extend(
            [db_t-qry_t 
            for qry_t in hash_DICT2[element] 
            for db_t in hash_DICT1[element] ])
    return vector

output_vector = GetPairDiff(hash_DICT1, hash_DICT2)
```

Performance comparison:

```
python  : 0.00824 s
c++     : 0.04286 s
```

The implementation by c++ takes about 5 times the time taken !!!

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for your comment, i have updated accordingly.
May i know where exactly do you mean to use `const&`.
Also, how do i replace the usage of `count` with `find` ?

Comment: Sure, I made an answer to show it instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You do a lot of copying where you should be using `const&`.
- You don't save search results. You should use `find` instead of `count` and then use the result.
- `push_back` to a `vector` may be made faster by `reserve()`ing the number of elements you need to store if you know the number in advance.

Fixing these issues could result in something like this (requires C++17):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using container = std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_set<int>>;

std::vector<int> GetPairDiff(const container& hash_DICT1,
                             const container& hash_DICT2) {
    // Init
    std::vector<int> output_vector;

    // Get intersection
    for(auto& [curr_key2, curr_set2] : hash_DICT2) {
        // use find() instead of count()
        if(auto it1 = hash_DICT1.find(curr_key2); it1 != hash_DICT1.end()) {
            auto& curr_set1 = it1->second;

            // Reserve the space you know you'll need for this iteration. Note:
            // This might be a pessimizing optimization so try with and without it.
            output_vector.reserve(curr_set1.size() * curr_set2.size() +
                                  output_vector.size());

            // Calculate pairwise difference
            for(auto& s1v : curr_set1) {
                for(auto& s2v : curr_set2) {
                    output_vector.emplace_back(s2v - s1v);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return output_vector;
}

int main() {
    container hash_DICT1{{1, {1, 2, 3}}, 
                         {2, {4, 5, 6}}};
    container hash_DICT2{{1, {11, 12, 13}},
                         {3, {4, 5, 6}}};

    auto result = GetPairDiff(hash_DICT1, hash_DICT2);

    for(int v : result) {
        std::cout << v << '\n';
    }
}
```

This is more than 8 times as fast as the python version for these containers on my computer compiled with `g++ -std=c++17 -O3`.

---

Here's a C++11 version of the same program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using container = std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_set<int>>;

std::vector<int> GetPairDiff(const container& hash_DICT1,
                             const container& hash_DICT2) {
    // Init
    std::vector<int> output_vector;

    // Get intersection
    for(auto& curr_pair2 : hash_DICT2) {
        auto& curr_key2 = curr_pair2.first;
        auto& curr_set2 = curr_pair2.second;
        // use find() instead of count()
        auto it1 = hash_DICT1.find(curr_key2);
        if(it1 != hash_DICT1.end()) {
            auto& curr_set1 = it1->second;

            // Reserve the space you know you'll need for this iteration. Note:
            // This might be a pessimizing optimization so try with and without it.
            output_vector.reserve(curr_set1.size() * curr_set2.size() +
                                  output_vector.size());

            // Calculate pairwise difference
            for(auto& s1v : curr_set1) {
                for(auto& s2v : curr_set2) {
                    output_vector.emplace_back(s2v - s1v);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return output_vector;
}

int main() {
    container hash_DICT1{{1, {1, 2, 3}}, 
                         {2, {4, 5, 6}}};
    container hash_DICT2{{1, {11, 12, 13}},
                         {3, {4, 5, 6}}};

    auto result = GetPairDiff(hash_DICT1, hash_DICT2);

    for(int v : result) {
        std::cout << v << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried your function, compiled with `g++ -std=c++17 -O3`, but for the line
`for(const auto& [curr_key2, curr_set2] : hash_DICT2) {` , i get the following errors `error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token` `error: expected ‘;’ before ‘[’ token` `error: ‘curr_key2’ was not declared in this scope`

Comment: i think my g++ is not a newer version, hence unable to support this. Do you mind including in your solution with a script that works for c++11 ?

Comment: @leonardltk1 Ok, I suspect that your `g++ --version` is somewhere between 5.1 and 6.4, which supports C++17 but apparently without [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding). I've added a C++11 version at the botom of the answer.

Comment: thanks, it works now! is there difference in speed when u use the solution for `c++17` as compared to the one for `c++11`?

Comment: @leonardltk1 I doubt it. I think the maturity of the compiler affects this more than the version of the language. Btw, I just made a performance-test setting up 10000 keys/10 values per set and 1000 keys/1 value per set with an intersection of 100 keys (just a guess). https://quick-bench.com/q/Zhy6QIL_4ASlSIb2ab1mfo6-h8c
It shows that the `reserve` I suggested is _really_ destroying the performance. It would be much better to make _one_ `reserve` at the start - or remove the `reserve` completely.

Comment: haha yeah i did try that. It jumped from 0.001 seconds to 6 seconds ><. i ended up reserving an approximate number based on the data distribution i was working on.

Comment: @leonardltk1 That sounds like a good approach. If the intersection and set sizes vary too much it _may_ be worth making a first iteration through the containers to calculate the exact number of elements to `reserve` space for, but I suspect that's a micro optimization that one can live without.

Comment: Btw, i want to add that because my elements in the set are small `O(1)`, it seems faster if i use `set` instead of `unordered_set`. Probably because the constant `O(k)` lookup of `unordered_set` is more than `O(log n)` lookup of `set` for small n.

Comment: @leonardltk1 Yes, that sounds reasonable.  Testing on real data is always good to get the best performance :-) I added the `container` alias to make it easy to try out different combinations.